# O que é e para que serve o service fabric

Tags: .net, microsoft-azure, cloud, cross-platform, microsserviços

No meu ponto de vista a Microsoft tem feito um excelente trabalho para sopurtar várias plataformas últimamente. Tudo comecou quando eles disponibilizaram o código da plataforma .Net.

Parece que mais uma vez eles estão a investir em sopurtar várias plataformas, desta vez na cloud! Eles disponibilizam uma nova framework chamada [Service Fabric](https://acom.azurecomcdn.net/80C57D/cdn/mediahandler/docarticles/dpsmedia-prod/azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-overview/20160926102123/service-fabric-overview.png) que pode ser *deployed* para qualquer tipo de cloud (pelo que percebi).

Isto é práticamente tudo o que sei sobre o Service Fabric. Podem explicar com mais detlhes para que ele serve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**O que é?**

[Service Fabric](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/learning-paths/service-fabric/) é uma plataforma de sistemas distribuídos que facilita o empacotamento, implantação e gerenciamento de microsserviços escalonáveis e confiáveis. Ele resolve os desafios significativos de desenvolvimento e gerenciamento de aplicativos em nuvem. Fazendo com que desenvolvedores e administradores possam evitar a resolução de problemas complexos de infraestrutura e se concentrarem na implementação de cargas de trabalho essenciais e exigentes sabendo que elas são escalonáveis, confiáveis e gerenciáveis.

**Para que serve?**

O Service Fabric permite criar e gerenciar aplicativos escalonáveis e confiáveis compostos por microsserviços executados a uma densidade bastante alta em um pool compartilhado de computadores (conhecido como um cluster). Ele fornece um tempo de execução sofisticado para criação de microsserviços distribuídos, escalonáveis, com e sem estado. Ele também fornece recursos abrangentes de gerenciamento de aplicativos para provisionamento, implantação, monitoramento, atualização/aplicação de patch e exclusão de aplicativos implantados.

Você pode criar clusters do Service Fabric em muitos ambientes, incluindo o Azure ou no local, no Windows Server ou no Linux. Além disso, o ambiente de desenvolvimento no SDK é idêntico ao ambiente de produção, sem nenhum emulador envolvido. Em outras palavras, se ele for executado no cluster de desenvolvimento local, ele será implantado no mesmo cluster em outros ambientes.

**Principais recursos**

Estes são os principais recursos listados na [Visão geral da Service Fabric](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/service-fabric-overview/):

> - Desenvolver aplicativos massivamente escalonáveis, que são autorrecuperáveis.
> - Desenvolva aplicativos compostos por microsserviços usando o modelo de programação do Service Fabric. Ou, simplesmente executáveis
>     convidado de host e outras estruturas de aplicativo de sua escolha,
>     como ASP.NET Core 1 ou Node.js.
> - Desenvolva microsserviços com e sem monitoração de estado altamente confiáveis.
> - Simplifique o design do seu aplicativo usando microsserviços com monitoramento de estado em vez de caches e filas.
> - Implante no Azure ou em nuvens locais que executam o Windows Server ou o Linux sem qualquer mudança no código. Escreva uma vez em qualquer
>     lugar e implante em qualquer cluster do Service Fabric.
> - Desenvolver usando uma abordagem "datacenter no seu computador". O ambiente de desenvolvimento local usa o mesmo código que é executado
>     nos datacenters do Azure.
> - Implantar aplicativos em segundos.
> - Implantar aplicativos em densidade mais alta do que as máquinas virtuais, implantando centenas ou milhares de aplicativos por
>     computador.
> - Implantar diferentes versões do mesmo aplicativo lado a lado, cada um atualizável de modo independente.
> - Gerenciar o ciclo de vida dos seus aplicativos com estado sem nenhum tempo de inatividade, incluindo atualizações imediatas ou não.
> - Gerenciar aplicativos usando APIs .NET, PowerShell ou interfaces REST.
> - Atualizar microsserviços e aplicar patch neles dentro dos aplicativos de modo independente.
> - Monitorar e diagnosticar a integridade de seus aplicativos e definir políticas para realizar reparos automáticos.
> - Escalar vertical ou horizontalmente o cluster do Service Fabric com facilidade, sabendo que os aplicativos são dimensionados de acordo com
>     os recursos disponíveis.
> - Observar o balanceador de recursos de auto-recuperação administrar a redistribuição de aplicativos no cluster. O Service Fabric se
>     recupera de falhas e otimiza a distribuição a distribuição de carga
>     com base nos recursos disponíveis.

Referência:

- [Visão geral da Service Fabric](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/service-fabric-overview/)
- [Service Fabric](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/learning-paths/service-fabric/)